# Mount partition with truecrypt using the commandline

Tags: mount, devices, raspberry-pi, raspbian, truecrypt

I'm trying to mount a encrypted HDD with truecrypt, but I cann't find the device. Where can I finde my HDD and what is the command to mount it in truecrypt?

I'm using Raspbian on Raspberypi.